# Selecting specific registers for external calls

Tags: c, windows, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

I'm very new to assembly and trying to learn myself.

So far, I've learned that, depending on the number of arguments passed from caller to callee, if there are only a few number of arguments to pass, in stead of push / pop operations, only some specific registers are used.

- For example, when passing arguments to a swap function `void asm_swap(int *x, int *y)`, the C compiler uses registers **rcx** and **rdx** registers to pass the addresses of the variables (no return value needed in this case). Switching from *_cdecl* to *_fastcall* didn't make any difference.
- For another function `int asm_fact(int x)`, that is to compute the factorial of x, C compiler uses **rcx** to pass the value of x, and **rax** to return the computed factorial. Again, switching from *_cdecl* to *_fastcall* didn't make any difference.

Connected to the issue, I have two questions:

1. Can I deduce an assertion that, whenever I compile the same code, caller will definitely use the same registers for sending and receiving data?
2. Is there a way to select specific registers as a tool to pass variables (say, for the function `asm_fact`, I'd prefer to use the **rdx** to hold the value of x, rather than **rcx**?

System: Windows 10 (64), VS-2013.

Sample code:
file "main.c"

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern void asm_swap();
extern signed long long int asm_fact();

typedef signed long long int sint64;

sint64 fact_sint64(sint64 n) {
    sint64 ret = (sint64)1;
    if (n > (sint64)1) {
        while (n > (sint64)1) {
            ret *= n--;
        }
    }
    return (ret);
}

void swap_sint64(sint64 *a, sint64 *b) {
    sint64 t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

int main(void) {
    sint64 x, y;
    x = 8;
    y = 3;
    printf("(initial)     ->   x = %lli     y = %lli\n\n", x, y);
    swap_sint64(&x, &y);
    printf("(swap in c)   ->   x = %lli     y = %lli\n\n", x, y);
    asm_swap(&x, &y);
    printf("(swap in asm) ->   x = %lli     y = %lli\n\n", x, y);
    y = fact_sint64(x);
    printf("(fact in c)   ->   fact(%lli) = %lli\n\n", x, fact_sint64(x));
    y = asm_fact(x);
    printf("(fact in asm) ->   fact(%lli) = %lli\n\n", x, y);
    getchar();
    return (0);
}
```

file "Assembly.asm64"

```
.data

.code
asm_swap proc
    mov r8, [rcx]
    mov r9, [rdx]
    mov [rcx], r9
    mov [rdx], r8
    ret
asm_swap endp

asm_fact proc
    mov rax, 1
    cmp rcx, 1
    jle $exit@fact
$loop@fact:
    imul rax, rcx
    dec rcx
    cmp rcx, 1
    jg $loop@fact
$exit@fact:
    ret
asm_fact endp
end
```

Comment: 1) yes 2) no. See [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthk2dkh.aspx)

Comment: This is part of the *calling conventions*, which are part of the ABI (*application binary interface*) defined by the implementation.

Comment: @Jester: Thanks a lot. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For windows there is an ABI which specifies

1. How parameters are passed
2. Which registers need to be preserved within a call

[Msdn:microsoft calling conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z1stfyw.aspx)

In order to call as a C function, you should abide by these rules.

You must preserve the non-volatile registers (save and restore them)